# jQuery script runs in console but not from the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    sweetAlert("a");// This is just a test, and it runs successfully by the way!!!
});

$("#login").keyup(check);

function check() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,"_"));
}
```

The browser is loading the file, I checked it from the inspector, plus it runs the .ready script. But it's not working with .keyup. Then when I copy/paste the line

```
$("#login").keyup(check);
```

in the console it works successfully.

Here's the html form if needed :

```
<input type="text" name="login" id="login"/>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try putting the keyup inside the document ready?

Comment: As Antonio implies, it works successfully in the console because your input has already loaded into the DOM by the time you're running something in the console. You're trying to attach the keyup handler to it before it's loaded into the DOM. If you include it in document ready then it won't run until the DOM is ready.

Comment: No I didn't but I'm going to try it. P.S: Tha same coding pattern is used in other pages of the website and it works perfectly, that's what's bothering me.

Comment: @KhalilHamani if the keypup is bound after the element is rendered in the DOM on the other page that would be the reason why it "works" there. If the element doesn't exist it can't bind. An alternative would be to investigate `on` or `live` depending on which version of jquery you are running.

Comment: @scrappedcola Please don't advice people to use `live` or any jQuery that's less than `1.7.2`. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I wasn't advising the use of a version less than 1.7.2. If they had indicated version I wouldn't bring up live. Ideally yes they wouldn't use anything that supports live, however there are real life use cases where one is limited by the version and live would be the only thing available.

Comment: @scrappedcola I agree with you, please don't get offended. I am sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the `.keyup` inside the `document` ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    sweetAlert("a");// This is just a test, and it runs successfully by the way!!!
    $("#login").keyup(check);
});
```

The reason is, whatever code you write inside `$(document).ready(function() {` will get executed only after loading of all DOM Elements. When you say it doesn't work, when `$("#login").keyup(check);` executes, the `#login` would not have loaded. The `$(document).ready(function() {` will have it executed for you once all the elements are loaded. Whatever executes in the Console, gets executed after the document is fully loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but this makes me want to ask why, when using the same coding pattern (handlers outside '.ready'), it works in other pages ?

Comment: @KhalilHamani It might work, if you are loading scripts at the end of the `body` after loading all the components.